# C# Task - Linked cancellation token not working

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

Please if someone could help me. 
I'm trying to use TPL linked cancellation tokens. Issue is that after cancellation of the main CancellationTokenSource, value of linked token's property IsCancellationRequested is still "false".

I'm starting two tasks, just to be sure - but it should be the same thing. To the first I pass CancellationToken, and to the second I pass CancellationTokenSource. The behaviour is the same: In the while loops - condition linkedToken.IsCancellationRequested stays "false" after cancellation.

Here is the code I am using:

```
public class Manager
{
    private Task tokenTask;
    private Task sourceTask;
    private CancellationTokenSource mainCancelationTokenSource;
    private CancellationToken mainToken;

    public Manager()
    {
        this.mainCancelationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        this.mainToken = mainCancelationTokenSource.Token;
        this.mainToken.Register(MainCanceled);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Workers w = new Workers();
        tokenTask = Task.Run(() => w.DoWorkToken(mainToken), mainToken);
        sourceTask = Task.Run(() => w.DoWorkSource(mainCancelationTokenSource), mainCancelationTokenSource.Token);

    }
    public void Cancel()
    {
        mainCancelationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    private void MainCanceled()
    {
        try
        {
            tokenTask.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        try
        {
            sourceTask.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}

class Workers
{
    public void DoWorkToken(CancellationToken mainToken)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource linkedCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(mainToken);
        CancellationToken linkedToken = linkedCts.Token;

        while (!linkedToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            Task.Delay(200 * r.Next(1, 11)).Wait();
        }

        linkedToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }

    public void DoWorkSource(CancellationTokenSource mainCts)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource linkedCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(mainCts.Token);

        while (!linkedCts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            Task.Delay(200 * r.Next(1, 11)).Wait();
        }

        linkedCts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}
```

To start this code from a console application Main method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            Manager manager = new Manager();
            manager.Start();
            //Console.ReadKey();

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            manager.Cancel();
   }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source of this problem is this line:

```
this.mainToken.Register(MainCanceled);
```

You register a callback to execute when token is cancelled. Internally that callback is delegated to the parent `CancellationTokenSource` and is put in some list of callbacks to execute when source cancellation is requested. In that handler you do

```
tokenTask.Wait();
sourceTask.Wait();
```

So this callback will not be completed until related tasks are completed.
In tasks you do this

```
while (!linkedToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
    // loop here
}
```

So tasks will not be completed until cancellation is requested.

Now to the tricky part: when you create linked token source

```
CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(mainToken)
```

It will **also** put a callback in the list of parent (mainToken) token source. When this callback is executed - linked token source becomes cancelled too. This callback will be **after** your callback in the list.

So you are deadlocked, because first callback (yours) waits for tasks to complete, tasks wait for linked token IsCancellationRequested equals true, and linked token source waits for it's own callback to complete to set this flag.

To solve this issue, just remove the callback, or write it in a way that it does not block waiting for related task to complete, or change tasks to not wait on *linked* token source IsCancellationRequested flag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I remove the callback, everything works. But just to be clear, I've changed condition in while loops to: `while (!mainToken.IsCancellationRequested)`. (This is the token from the source that is canceled - in the other while loop I put condition with the source respectively). And I've added the callback back. This token gets cancelled, tasks finishes, Wait() in callback finishes and everything works. Can I conclude that linked source is put to this "callback" list, but the source itself gets cancelled despite the registered callback?

Comment: @Thomas you are right and I was partially wrong, I have updated my answer.